# Reduced TPS using AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

We are conducting several performance tests in our integration environment. Our integration is depicted like this:

AWS API Gateway -> AWS App Load Balancer -> AWS ECS (docker) x 3 (using AutoScaling)

Our initial results show:

TPS = 198, 95% Response Time = 442 ms, Requests = 61790 during 5 minutes performance tests.

When we skip the API Gateway and send all the load to the Application Load Balancer we got:

TPS = 901, 95% Response Time = 433 ms, Requests = 280399 during 5 minutes performance tests.

We have disabled the throttling option in the API Gateway but there's no difference. How can I configure the AWS API Gateway in order to achieve more TPS?

Next you can find CFN code that uses Lambda instead of AWS ECS but suffers from the same TPS issue:

**deploy.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ex

AWS_REGION="us-east-1"

CLOUD_FORMATION_STACK_NAME="APILowTPSTest"
CLOUD_FORMATION_TEMPLATE_FILE="service.yaml"
CLOUD_FORMATION_CAPABILITIES="CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM"

aws --region "${AWS_REGION}" cloudformation deploy \
    --template-file "${CLOUD_FORMATION_TEMPLATE_FILE}" \
    --stack-name "${CLOUD_FORMATION_STACK_NAME}" \
    --capabilities "${CLOUD_FORMATION_CAPABILITIES}" \
    --no-fail-on-empty-changeset \
    --tags \
        Name="${CLOUD_FORMATION_STACK_NAME}-Stack" \
    --parameter-overrides \
        EnvironmentName="${CLOUD_FORMATION_STACK_NAME}" \
        LambdaFunctionName="API-Tps-Mock-Test"
```

**service.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >
  This template deploys a simple environment using an API Gateway and a Lambda Function for Performances tests purposes

Parameters:

  EnvironmentName:
    Description: Environment Name (Used to name some resources)
    Type: String

  LambdaFunctionName:
    Description: Lambda function that works as mock
    Type: String

Resources:

  LambdaIAMRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
      Policies:
        - PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Effect: Allow
                Resource:
                  - !Sub arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/${LambdaFunctionName}:*
          PolicyName: lambda

  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: Authorization Lambda Function for NCR
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaFunctionName
      Handler: index.handler
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 3
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaIAMRole.Arn
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          exports.handler = (event, context) => {
              return new Promise((resolve) => resolve({
                  isBase64Encoded: false,
                  body: JSON.stringify({ Result: "All Good!" }),                  
                  statusCode: 200,
              }));
          }

  ApiGateway:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi    
      Properties:
        Name: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref EnvironmentName, "API" ] ]
        Description: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref EnvironmentName, "API Gateway deployed to test TPS" ] ]
        EndpointConfiguration:
          Types:
            - REGIONAL
        Tags:
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join [ "-", [ "API", !Ref EnvironmentName ] ]

  ApiLambdaPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaFunction
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn:
        !Join
          - ''
          - - 'arn:aws:execute-api:'
            - !Ref AWS::Region
            - ':'
            - !Ref AWS::AccountId
            - ':'
            - !Ref ApiGateway
            - '/*/*/*'

  SubRootResource:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
      ParentId: !GetAtt ApiGateway.RootResourceId
      PathPart: "v1"

  SingleRequestResource:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
      ParentId: !Ref SubRootResource
      PathPart: "test"

  ApiGatewaySingleRequestMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      ResourceId: !Ref SingleRequestResource
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
      AuthorizationType: "NONE"
      HttpMethod: "POST"
      Integration:
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        IntegrationHttpMethod: "POST"
        Uri: !Sub
          - 'arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations'
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt "LambdaFunction.Arn"

  ApiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    DependsOn:
      - ApiGatewaySingleRequestMethod
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway

  APIStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      DeploymentId: !Ref ApiGatewayDeployment
      MethodSettings:
        - HttpMethod: '*'
          LoggingLevel: INFO
          ResourcePath: /*
          DataTraceEnabled: true
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
      StageName: 'dev'
```

Comment: There's a lot of play here, as with any performance related question. How are you directing to the ALB? Are you calling a custom domain? The API endpoint? Is it private? Regional? An edge optimised endpoint? Are you running the tests from one location? We need much much more information before we can help :)

Comment: Hi Ermiya, thanks for your reply. How are you directing to the ALB? R/. Using the ALB domain URL provided by AWS. Are you calling a custom domain? R/. No. The API endpoint? R/. It's private, using VPC Link with Network LB + Application LB, we don't use custom domain, but the one provided by AWS. Regional? R/. Yes. We created a Server in the same region (us-east-1) that we use as injector.

Comment: do you have any terraform for your infrastructure?

Comment: No, we use cloudformation.

Comment: Sorry I meant any IaC in general - can you please share your CFN code?

Comment: Besides CFN no. There are some proprietary components in our deployment, but let me share with you a simplify deployment that suffers of the same issue of reduced TPS.